# Scrolling to the top without href...?

Tags: jquery

Here's what I started out with,

```
   $("a[href='#top']").click(function() {
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
   return false;
    });
```

Which works great with

```
<a href="#top">...</a>
```

However, I need something similar that works without a link, something like...

```
<li id="top">....</li>
```

I tried this

```
  $("#top").click(function() {
          $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
          return false;
        });
```

But it doesn't work on my end.

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What debugging have you performed?

Comment: works for me, can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yep, [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mz5HG/1/) shows that your code should work.

Comment: Not on my end, http://jsfiddle.net/WRmPz/

Comment: This did the trick, $("li#top")

Comment: You have two elements with `id="top"` in your jsfiddle.  Remove the first one and your jsfiddle will work without `li#top`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your HTML, not your JavaScript.  It is not valid to have two elements with identical `id` attributes in your HTML.  jQuery (actually the underlying JavaScript) will only select the *first* of these elements when the ID selector is used, so `#top` selects the `<a>`.  Your selector of `li#top` is more restrictive, but you can see a similar effect if you reverse the element order: http://jsfiddle.net/WRmPz/10/

It is imperative that all of your elements have unique IDs for this and many other reasons.

By the way, the `return false` is not necessary for the `<li>`, (nor would it be necessary for `<a>` without `href`).  If you were to use the latter, it would be better to pass in the event object and call `e.preventDefault()`: http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/